# How to return back twice in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, there is a function `return back();`, which returns the user to the previous page. Is it possible to `return back();` more than once within one function to return the user back twice or several times? I tried

```
public function ....()
{
  return back();
  return back();
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: You can directly redirect at perticular page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, but you could use [session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session) system to save URLs of 2-3-4 pages back. Use `Session::` facade or `session()` helper for [shorter syntax](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#use-shorter-and-more-readable-syntax-where-possible):

```
$links = session()->has('links') ? session('links') : [];
$currentLink = request()->path(); // Getting current URI like 'category/books/'
array_unshift($links, $currentLink); // Putting it in the beginning of links array
session(['links' => $links]); // Saving links array to the session
```

And to use it:

```
return redirect(session('links')[2]); // Will redirect 2 links back
```

Comment: Hi, where will I put this? which page? the previous page? sorry i'm just new in laravel. thanks!

Comment: @Lito - for example in a middleware ( https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware ). Remember to put this middleware inside kernel.php file inside the $middlewareGroups array in the 'web' key, to avoid problems with session not started yet ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797952/session-not-working-in-middleware-laravel-5 ).

Answer (score 3):

it works for me `Redirect::to($request->request->get('http_referrer'))`

Comment: Hi! while this answer may solve OP's problem, it is discouraged to post code only answers on SO. Providing some explanation will help OP understand this solution better, while also contributing to SO's mission of providing quality solutions to future users of the site. Thanks!