# How to correctly redirect after doing POST in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have multiple routes with comments and when I click reply I get redirected to a route where I can post a reply to a comment. How can I correctly store the route from where I came and then redirect back to it after posting the reply?

I considered passing the URL::previous as a param and storing it into a hidden input, but if the page gets refreshed by the user it gets empty. Another way might be store in the session, but then I don't know how to reliably expire it...

Comment: Do like this $request->session()->put('previous-url', '/user/demo');
$previous_url = Session::get('previous-url'); 
return redirect()->to($previous_url);

Answer (score 2):

Redirect back with success message

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Data added successfully');
```

Comment: Try to store url in session and then get

Answer (score 1):

use `return redirect()->back();`

Comment: No, this would return user to page where he wrote his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return Redirect::back()` function for the previous URL.

Comment: No, this would return user to page where he wrote his comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return Redirect::back();` or `return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#whatever");`

Comment: No, this would return user to page where he wrote his comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep 2-3-4-5 URLs in a session and you don't need to expire it. You can just limit number of kept URLs. Also, please check my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098589/how-to-return-back-twice-in-laravel).

Answer (score 0):

Store url in the session when user access page, when you have your reply button. You dont have to expire it, it will get automaticaly updated when user visit next page with reply button.

```
session(['last_url' => 'Request::fullUrl()']);
```

Also dont forget to use namespace

```
Use Request;
```

If you really want to discard value from session after user redirects, you can use this:

```
return redirect()->url(Session::pull('last_url'));
```

And namespace

```
Use Session;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do `return redirect()->back();`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

First store url in session

```
$request->session()->put('previous-url', '/user/demo');
```

Use like this

```
$previous_url = Session::get('previous-url'); 
return redirect()->to($previous_url);
```