# How to redirect to two step backwards in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

For example 
 In controller I have a store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
 ....
 return redirect()->back();
 }
```

After store function is called, it goes to the create.blade.php view because of ***return redirect()->back()***.
But I want to redirect to further one step backwards.
How can I do that ? Thank You

Comment: If you know the url form the place where you want to send it, then just send/redirect it to that url.

Comment: You cannot do it twice because laravel uses HTTP_REFERER to find the recent url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return back twice in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098589/how-to-return-back-twice-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Session system to save the URL all pages back. Check below steps to redirect 2 or 3 backward URL redirect.

1) First, you can get the all URLs from session system variable.

```
$urls = array();
  if(Session::has('links')){
     $urls[] = Session::get('links')
  }
```

2) Then get the current page url.

```
  $currentUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

3) Mapping with current url to other all url.

```
array_unshift($urls, $currentUrl);
  Session::flash('urls', $urls);
```

4) Get all Links fetch from session system like below

```
  $links = Session::get('urls');
```

5) Then You can redirect to a particular page.

```
   return redirect($links[2]);
```

Comment: Dude, you've just copied the code [from my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098589/how-to-return-back-twice-in-laravel) (see [version of the answer before the last edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36098635/6)). I don't mind if you would add something cool to the idea. I mean like a better solution. But why just copy it? BTW, I've just refactored code to make it modern and more elegant.

Comment: $urls = array();
  if(Session::has('links')){
     $urls[] = Session::get('links');
  }

; is missing