# How to call this route for back button , Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having problems with the back button of my Createoffice form and Editoffice form it doesn't goes back to the page where the offices are listed

I tried using this:

```
  <a href="{{ route('building', $building->id) }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
```

but nah its not working here's the error:

```
Undefined variable: building (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\createoffice.blade.php)
```

heres my routes:

```
  Route::get('building/{id}', 'PageController@show');

  Route::get('office/{id}', 'OfficeController@show')->name('officeMenu');

  Route::get('offices', 'OfficeController@index');

  Route::get('building/{id}/offices/create', 'OfficeController@create')->name('createofficeform');

  Route::post('building/{id}/offices/create/store', 'OfficeController@store')->name('createoffice');

  Route::get('building/{id}/offices/edit', 'OfficeController@edit')->name('editofficeform');

  Route::post('building/{id}/offices/edit', 'OfficeController@update')->name('editoffice');
```

This is how I make the data display

PageController.php

```
     public function buildings(){
            $buildings = Building::paginate(10);
            return view('buildings')->with('buildings', $buildings);
        }

        public function show($id){
            $building = Building::find($id);
            $offices = Office::where('building_id', $id)->orderBy('floor')->get();
            return view('building')->with('building', $building)->with('offices', $offices);

} }
```

OfficeController.php

class OfficeController extends Controller
{

```
   /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $search = \Request::get('search');

        $offices = Office::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')->get();
        return view('search')->with('offices', $offices)->with('search', $search);

      }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function create($id)
    {

        return view('createoffice')->with('id', $id);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $office = new Office();
        $office->name =$request->officename;
        $office->floor = $request->floor;
        $office->building_id = $id;
        $office->save();

        return redirect()->back();

         \Session::flash('building_flash', 'Created successfully!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $office = Office::find($id);
        return view('office')->withOffice($office);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $office = Office::find($id);
        return view('editoffice')->withOffice($office)->with('id',$id);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $office = Office::find($id);
        $office->name =$request->officename;
        $office->floor = $request->floor;
        $office->update();

          \Session::flash('building_flash', 'Updated successfully!');
          return redirect()->back();

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $office = Office::find($id);
        $office->delete();
\Session::flash('building_flash_delete', 'Deleted successfully!');
        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

Comment: It seems like the variable `$building` of which you try to fetch the ID is undefined. Could you please show some more of your blade view code and the controller you use for this page?

Comment: <a href="{{ route('offices') }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>

Comment: http://localhost:8000/building/1       this is the link that I want to the back button to go I have a lot of building with different id its like : 
http://localhost:8000/building/1   
http://localhost:8000/building/2

Comment: `<a href="{{ route('building/'. $building->id) }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>`

Comment: Same error shown above @Sohel0415

Comment: you need to show us your implementation of that controller method, how you are fetching data

Comment: I edited the code take a look @Sohel0415

Comment: show us your create and store implementation and your view file like createoffice.blade.php

Comment: `{{ route('building', $building->id) }}`: You don't have a route named 'building' and that's not the correct way to pass parameters to a route. Take a look at @linktoahref 's answer

Comment: @kerbholz the error says `$building` is undefined.

Comment: There it is the full controller @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: There it is the full controller @Sohel0415

Comment: Yes, nowhere in your OfficeController do you assign any $building. (Sorry @AlexeyMezenin ;))

Comment: @kerbholz not me. I'm not OP. )

Answer (score 2):

Name your route

```
Route::get('building/{id}', 'PageController@show')->name('building');
```

and pass the variable as second argument to route

```
<a href="{{ route('building', ['id' => $id] ) }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes)

Comment: But the `$building` variable is undefined.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin variable corrected as per `'OfficeController@create'`

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do that by Java Script

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>

function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hardcode the link:

```
<a href="{{ url('building/' . $id) }}"
```

Or you can use the [`url()->previous()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#accessing-the-current-url) method:

```
<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}"
```

Comment: http://localhost:8000/building/1       this is the link that I want to the back button to go I have a lot of building with different id its like : 
http://localhost:8000/building/1   
http://localhost:8000/building/2

Comment: Oh I've tried this but the problem of this one is when I click the create or update button it doesnt go back it stays on the page @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj please show full controller method and full view. Or you can just [go 2 links back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36098635/1227923) if you use a bunch of redirects.

Comment: Im having error in the Edit back button the create works but the edit it doesnt   this is the error : Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\building.blade.php)  @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj it's not related to the question, it means now it's working and you're getting next error. To be able to help you with this one I need to see the full error message and the `building.blade.php`. I recommend you to ask a new question and add the view and the error message.

Comment: can we do this for routes usin post methods, if not is there a way to route back to a post route

Answer (score 0):

Just call index route :

```
<a href="{{ route('offices') }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
```

Comment: localhost:8000/building/1 this is the link that I want to the back button to go I have a lot of building with different id its like : localhost:8000/building/1 localhost:8000/building/2  @Maraboc