# EditForm back button and how to return redirect in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this edit form and the back button is not working, So when I clicked the back button it shows this error,

This is the backbutton for my createOffice I tried applying it to my EditOffice backbutton and it didnt work:

```
 <a href="{{ route('building', ['id' => $id] ) }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
```

Also, how do I make the UpdateOffice button when clicked it goes back to the page for the list of offices I'm using return redirect()->back(); and it stays in the edit form page.. whats the right code for this?

Here are the codes

OfficeController.php

```
public function index()
{

    $search = \Request::get('search');

    $offices = Office::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')->get();
    return view('search')->with('offices', $offices)->with('search', $search);

  }

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function create($id)
{

    return view('createoffice')->with('id', $id);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $office = new Office();
    $office->name =$request->officename;
    $office->floor = $request->floor;
    $office->building_id = $id;
    $office->save();

     \Session::flash('building_flash', 'Created successfully!');

    return redirect()->back();


}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $office = Office::find($id);
    return view('office')->withOffice($office);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $office = Office::find($id);
    return view('editoffice')->withOffice($office)->with('id',$id);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $office = Office::find($id);
    $office->name =$request->officename;
    $office->floor = $request->floor;
    $office->update();

      \Session::flash('building_flash', 'Updated successfully!');
return redirect()->back();

}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
        $office = Office::find($id);
        $office->delete();
\Session::flash('building_flash_delete', 'Deleted successfully!');
        return redirect()->back();

    }
}
```

PageController.php

```
    class PageController extends Controller
    {
        public function buildings(){
            $buildings = Building::paginate(10);
            return view('buildings')->with('buildings', $buildings);
        }

        public function show($id){
            $building = Building::find($id);
            $offices = Office::where('building_id', $id)->orderBy('floor')->get();
            return view('building')->with('building', $building)->with('offices', $offices);


    } }
```

Building.blade.php

```
  @extends('layouts.main')
  @section('title',$building->name)
  @section('css')
  @stop
  @section('content')

  <div class="officebg">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="Bldgttl">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
          <img src="{{URL::to('/assets')}}/{{$building->picture}}" alt="" style="height:300px; width:500px;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          {{$building->name}}
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="rows">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6">
 @if(!Auth::guest())
                <a href="{{route('createofficeform', $building->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Create an Office</a>
  @endif
        </div>


      {!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>'offices','role'=>'search']) !!}
    <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
      <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Search</i>
       </button>
      </span>
        </div>
         {!! Form::close()!!}
          <hr>
    <table class="table">

      <thead>
          <th>Office Name</th>
          <th>Office Floor</th>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        @foreach($offices as $office)
          <tr>

            <td>{{$office->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$office->floor}}</td>
            <td class="a">
 @if(!Auth::guest())
              <a href="{{route('editofficeform', $office->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
              <a href="{{route('deleteoffice', $office->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
              @endif
            </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

    @endsection
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/', 'BuildingController@index')->name('index');

Route::get('building/{id}', 'PageController@show')->name('building');

Route::get('office/{id}', 'OfficeController@show')->name('officeMenu');

Route::get('offices', 'OfficeController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

  Route::get('buildings/create', 'BuildingController@create')->name('createbform');

  Route::post('building/create/store', 'BuildingController@saveBuilding')->name('createbuilding');

  Route::get('building/{id}/edit', 'BuildingController@edit');

  Route::post('building/{id}/edit', 'BuildingController@update')->name('editbuilding');

  Route::get('building/{id}/delete', 'BuildingController@destroy');

  Route::get('building/{id}/offices/create', 'OfficeController@create')->name('createofficeform');

  Route::post('building/{id}/offices/create/store', 'OfficeController@store')->name('createoffice');

Route::get('building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit', 'OfficeController@edit')->name('editofficeform');

Route::post('building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit', 'OfficeController@update')->name('editoffice');

  Route::get('offices/{id}/delete', 'OfficeController@destroy')->name('deleteoffice');
});
```

editoffice.blade.php

```
    @extends('layouts.main')
@section('title', 'Create an Office')
@section('content')

{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['editoffice', $id], 'class' => 'form')) !!}
<div class="container">

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('Office Name') !!}
                {!! Form::text('officename', $office->name,        array('required',
                          'class'=>'form-control',
                          'placeholder'=>'Office Name')) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('Office Floor') !!}
                {!! Form::text('floor', $office->floor,        array('required',
                          'class'=>'form-control',
                          'placeholder'=>'Office Floor')) !!}
            </div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Update Office',
      array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}


     <a href="{{ route('building', ['id' => $id] ) }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>



</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

@endsection
```

Comment: Please place this to the top of the view and show the output `{{ dd($building, $offices) }}`

Comment: Where should I put it? what php file @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: sometimes you have used 'building' and some times 'buildings' as attributes in the PageController 'with' function, use one name.

Comment: Oh its 2 different thing building is for actual building and buildings is for offices @Sameera

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj place it to the top of `building.blade.php`

Comment: Already done it, take a look @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: put a dd in $building = Building::find($id);
the dd($building); in PageController => show function.

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj it's weird. And what happens if you change `{{$office->name}}` to `{{ optional($office)->name}}`?

Comment: I have a lot of {{$office->name}} where spefically? @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @TeamPlarJarj in the `building.blade.php` you have only one `{{$office->name}}`

Comment: it shows this when I press the back button
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\building.blade.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call this route for back button , Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186813/how-to-call-this-route-for-back-button-laravel)

Comment: Nope thats for the createOffice.. this one is for the EditOffice @AbdullaNilam

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that I can see, is with your routes definitions and passing of parameters with nested routes. For example lets take edit office route;

```
Route::get('building/{id}/offices/edit', 'OfficeController@edit')->name('editofficeform');
```

This is actually a nested route which by definition should be expecting two parameters; (1) The `building_id` of the building you are editing, that you have specified as `{id}` (2) you should also pass the `office_id`, which will be the id of that specific office which you want to edit.

The correct route definition should be something like this;

```
Route::get('building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit', 'OfficeController@edit')->name('editofficeform');
```

And then on `building.blade.php` when you are specifying edit link like this;

```
<a href="{{route('editofficeform', $office->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

It should be changed to this;

```
<a href="{{route('editofficeform', ['id'=>$building->id, 'office_id'=>$office->id])}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

Here you will be passing the main building id and that specific office id which you can use however you want and can keep track of which building page you are on.

On controller side in `OfficeController.php` you can change your `edit()` action to this;

```
public function edit($id, $office_id)
{
    $office = Office::find($office_id);
    return view('editoffice')->withOffice($office)->with('id',$id);
}
```

Now you can use your same back button link on office edit form and it should work fine and should take you back to actual building page.

```
<a href="{{ route('building', ['id' => $id] ) }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
```

I hope this explanation helps to solve the any other issues of this kind as well.

## Update

As you have been having issue with other routes of this type. In `editoffice.blade.php`, you can update your form tag like this;

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['editoffice', ["id"=>$id, "office_id"=>$office->id]], 'class' => 'form')) !!}
```

And in `OfficeController.php` update your `update()` method to handle this additional parameter;

```
public function update(Request $request, $id, $office_id)
{
    $office = Office::find($office_id);
    $office->name =$request->officename;
    $office->floor = $request->floor;
    $office->update();

      \Session::flash('building_flash', 'Updated successfully!');
    //return redirect()->back();
    // You can replace this statement with the following to redirect the user to building page, rather than going back to edit form.
    return redirect()->route('building', $id);
}
```

You can use same analogy in `createoffice.blade.php` and similarly in `store()` method. Of-course there won't be any `office_id`.

Comment: <a href="{{route('editofficeform', ["id"=>$building->id, "office_id"=>$office->id])}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>   @tahir waseer there seems to be a problem

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\building.blade.php)    @tahir wwaseer

Comment: my bad:( use this one `<a href="{{route('editofficeform', ['id'=>$building->id, 'office_id'=>$office->id])}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>` @TeamPlarJarj

Comment: <a href="{{route('editofficeform', ["id"=>$building->id, "office_id"=>$office->id)]}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>  I change it to this seems fixed but when I click edit button it says this Undefined variable: office_id  @tahir waseer

Comment: Can you post the complete exception. Like where this error is occurring like this exception "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\building.blade.php)"

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\app\Http\Controllers\OfficeController.php  here @tahir waseer

Comment: public function edit($id)
    {
       
 
        $office = Office::find($office_id);
        return view('editoffice')->withOffice($office)->with('id',$id);
    }         
@tahir waseer

Comment: I've updated the answer to fix this issue. please change edit method accordingly.

Comment: I assume you have this line at top of controller. `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: editoffice] [URI: building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\editoffice.blade.php)     it shows this @tahir waseer

Comment: Ive updated my routes kindly check if there is any conflict with it @tahir waseer

Comment: You have your method definition like this; `public function edit(Request $request, $id)`?

Comment: No, im not able

Comment: What is error that you are getting now? where you are stuck?

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: editoffice] [URI: building/{id}/offices/{office_id}/edit]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Eguide\resources\views\editoffice.blade.php)    it says this i follow everything you said @tahir waseer

Comment: This is issue with `editoffice` route not with `editofficeform` route. And I think you have issue in your edit form, where you have your form tag. You are not defining the route properly. Please add your edit form to the post so I can see it.

Comment: You have problem with your form tag. I've updated the answer to solve that issue. Please look the answer.