# Previous page button where user data laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know if there is a function where I can go back to my page after I submit a data.

For example, page 1, I submit my name, address and when I click next to page 2, it will show qualification, school. And after that if I want to go back to page 1 and change the value how do I do that? Such as Changing Name from John to John Doe when I go back to page 1.

I look around and saw something like return back, but does that help? Or should I use session?

Currently, I am just using redirects in my controller to bring the user to another page

Controller: (have something like that inside now)

```
    public function UserInfo(Request $request){
     $shirtSize = new user_info;
     //get input data and some other stuff
        $id->user_infos()->save($user_info);


    return redirect(url('/userAddInfo/'.$id->id.'/AddInfo'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`url()->previous()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#accessing-the-current-url) method:

```
<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}">Back</a>
```

If you use redirects, you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36098635/1227923) to redirect two pages (requests) back.

Comment: Is there a need to put anything in the controller?

Comment: @Dkna no you don't need to.

Comment: Another thing, so if I put this in all my page, page 2, 3 and 4 inside the blade, it will return me back my old value and not create any new data when I click next am I right?

Comment: @Dkna if you're not using redirects, yes.

Comment: Erm, I think I should have said this in question sorry about that, I am using redirect in the controller

Comment: @Dkna did you try this method? If it doesn't work for you, try one from my updated answer. You may use it to redirect 2 pages back.

Comment: return redirect(session('links')[2]);  is the 2 here necessary? Like if I just want to redirect back 1 page do I just do, return redirect(session('links')); ?

Comment: @Dkna you can save URI in session only when you're returning a view. Then use the code to return just one page back.