# Laravel 5.4: How do I redirect back two pages with input?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I'm trying to redirect back two pages and have their input filled back in.

This is my sites flow:
1.Land on checkout page and fill it out. Hit submit.
2.Land on pin verification page where the customer enters their phone number to receive a pin code. They press submit.
3.They land on page where they enter the pin code that was sent to them.

They have 10 attempts to enter their pin code on the 3rd page. If it's incorrect after the 10th time I want to redirect back to the first page.

I know how to redirect back one page I can do 
`\Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors();` but how can I redirect back two pages with an error displayed and the form filled out with the original values?

How can I do this?

Comment: Show your code what you have done so far.

Comment: @commonsense I don't have any because i'm completely lost with this. I know how to redirect back one page with `\Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors();` but have no idea how to go back twice and have the form filled in again with an error.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just redirect `to()` or `route()`? If the first page, i.e. the checkout page, you're trying to redirect to after failing all attempts is always the same it doesn't make sense to redirect twice, that's just adding an unnesseccary request.

Comment: I was thinking that but how can I fill out the form with the inputs the user added?

Comment: Same way as you have with `back()` the input and errors need to be kept in the session. You may need to call `save()` on the session prior to the redirect.

Comment: call `save()` on the session? what do you mean? I don't think i've ever done this.

Comment: The `Session` facade has a `save()` method if you need to access the value immediately. Otherwise, it won't be accessible until the start of the next request lifecycle. You may not need this, just a thought I had after reading another question regarding sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Dont redirect back twice per se, that is, in pseudo-code **dont** attempt something like:

`\Redirect::back()::back()`

Largely because Laravel doesnt know the state / page 2 pages back. At best you can redirect back [once] based on `HTTP_REFERER` which is only the last URL visited.

Since you already know the page they should be redirected back too - why not just redirect directly to that URL?

> I was thinking that but how can I fill out the form with the inputs the user added?

Store this somewhere: session, cookie, database, perhaps pass in the query string....

Comment: This was my first solution but I was thinking there might be an alternate solution I didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36098635/1227923) to redirect two pages back. To pass the data add `with()`, `withInput()` and/or `withErrors()`:

```
return redirect(session('links')[2])->withInput()->withErrors();
```

You'll be able to read this data the same way you would do this with `back()`.