# How to go back 2 step in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How to go back  in two step in la ravel?

```
 return \Redirect::back();
```

i have tried to back 2 step  but i don't want to use store URL in local storage .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098589/how-to-return-back-twice-in-laravel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return back twice in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098589/how-to-return-back-twice-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SESSION` to store pages and redirect two times.

first of all we get current url like `'localhost.com/test/friend/'` after that we put it into array. after that you can use `return redirect(session('links')[2]);` to return twice.

```
$url = session()->has('url') ? session('url') : [];
$page = request()->path(); 
array_unshift($url, $page); 
session(['url' => $url]);
```

## 2

another solution is to use store each url.(not recommended)

```
session(['some_url' => request()->path()]);
```