# Laravel5 - can't get Sessions working

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

Im trying Laravel 5 and cant get Session working. Im inside a `Controller` and this is what ive done on an fresh setup and fresh controller:

```
\Request::session()->put('test', 'x');
var_dump(\Request::session()->get('test'));
```

This works as long as session is being written, and once you comment the first line there session value is gone on the next request.

Similarly, ive tried this `Session::` instead of `Request::session()` and still same result.

Comment: which session driver are you using?

Comment: file. But i tried array, apc etc as well

Comment: `array` won't work because it is not persistent.

Comment: have you tried saving `Request::session()->get('test')` to another variable and  dumping that variable out?

Comment: How You check is your session have that variable or not?

Answer (score 1):

Ok ive found the solution myself thanks to 2 posts:

[Laravel 5 - session doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346743/laravel-5-session-doesnt-work?rq=1)

[Session not working in middleware Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797952/session-not-working-in-middleware-laravel-5?rq=1)

---

1. After all the `OMG` buzz around Laravel being so so so simple lets dance in the rain!! the simplest thing in PHP such as `$_SESSION` now requires `\Request::session()` for which you need to `user Request`. then you need 2 different methods to save and get values from it instead of $_SESSION['x'] directly!!
2. Laravel (genius super alien tech) saves session at `TerminableMiddleware` instead of on spot, but DOESNOT mentions it on https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session. So you will need to explicitly call `Session::save()`!!

So there you go, 5 lines to do 1 line work of $_SESSION!

Comment: Laravel Session has nothing to do with $_SESSION.

Comment: Did you read the opening sentence on this page? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session It says exactly what $_SESSION is used for!

Comment: and if it doesnt have anything to do with $_SESSION, they doesnt mentioned `TerminableMiddleware` on that page of the guide?!

Comment: First: chill!, Second: $_SESSION is a super global variable in the first place. Laravel Session does a little bit more than just saving data to this varible.

Comment: Laravel does a bit little more for everything that is supposed to be simple in php. #OverEngineering!!

Comment: You could also use $_SESSION whenever you want to, you know.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using 5.2, make sure your controller is governed by the 'web' middleware group either via the route

```
$route->group([ 'middleware' => ['web'] ....
```

or by instantiating it in your controllers construct method;

```
$this->middleware('web');
```