# Laravel 5.4 middleware

Tags: php, laravel, session

Laravel 5.4  Session flash messages not working after adding all routes in custom middleware

here my route file code.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'loadsession'], function () {



});
```

Comment: can you put up the code from the `loadsession` middleware? is that route group in your `web.php` routes files?

Comment: laravel 5.4 has a problem working with session in the middleware. related post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797952/session-not-working-in-middleware-laravel-5

Comment: StartSession middleware hasn't booted before you're trying to use your loadsession middleware.

Answer (score 2):

Add web middleware to your route which persist your session data

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['loadsession','web']], function () {


});
```

Comment: thanks, @royallife, but after adding the web, I have another error "web class not found"?